# What does it mean to say that it has "opposite polarity"? Furthermore, what is meant by "isolation of the input and output ground references"?

Tags: power-electronics, dc-dc-converter, ground, polarity

I am currently reading the textbook *Fundamentals of Power Electronics*, third edition, by Robert W. Maksimovic and Dragan Erickson. In the introduction, the authors say the following:

> In a dc–dc converter, the dc input voltage is converted to a dc output voltage having a larger or smaller magnitude, possibly with opposite polarity or with isolation of the input and output ground references.

What does it mean to say that it has "opposite polarity"? Furthermore, what is meant by "isolation of the input and output ground references"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that voltage is always measured *between* two points.

**Isolated:** The input terminal and output terminal do not share a common reference. That is, the input voltage is measured between two terminals and the output voltage is measured between two different terminals. No pair of terminals amongst the four need to be at the same potential.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fY57g0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**Unisolated** There are only three terminals, not four, because the input and output both share a terminal thus reducing the number of terminals by one. There is one input terminal, one output terminal, and one reference terminal which is shared by both the input and output terminal. So the pair of terminals that the input voltage is measured between is the input terminal and GND, while the pair of terminals that the output voltage is measured between is the output terminal and GND.

An isolated converter becomes unisolated if you connect one of the output pins to one of the input pins such that they both share the same potential and become the same electrical node.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fF6dFQ.png)</sup>

**Opposite polarity:** Only applicable if the converter is not isolated. It means that if the input potential (i.e. positive or above) is on one side of the reference potential, the output potential is on the other side (i.e. negative or below).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you please clarify the difference between the "pins" and the "terminals" in the unisolated circuit? You say that there are only three pins, not four, because the input and output both share a pin, but you also imply that the input and output terminals are different, which confuses me.

Comment: An unisolated DC-DC converter will have three connection points which may also be called "pins" or "terminals".  A 12V->5V converter will have an input terminal for +12V, an output terminal for +5V, and a Ground/zero volt terminal which is shared by input and output.

Comment: @PeterBennett Ohh, I see; I misinterpreted what was written. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @ThePointer The very first sentence implies that voltage inputs (or output) must always use two terminals. You can't send a voltage signal with just one terminal.